# Using UI Router in order to implement a navbar/header that changes according to whether the user is logged in or not

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a navbar template that is meant to adapt and change according to whether or not the user is logged in.

I have a `root` state inherited by all the other states and an `authenticated` state inherited by all states that assume the user is logged in.

My `root` state:

```
.state('root', {
    abstract: true,
    template: '<ui-view />'
    data: {
        requiresLogin: false
    },
    views: {
        'header@': {
            //Issue: navbarCtrl is not defined here...
            templateUrl: 'app/navbar/views/navbar.view.html'
        },
        'footer@': {
            templateUrl: 'app/footer/views/footer.html'
        }
    }
})
```

and my `authenticated` state:

```
.state('authenticated', {
    abstract: true,
    parent: 'root',
    views: {
        'header@': {
            controller: 'NavbarCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/navbar/views/navbar.view.html'
        }
    },
    data: {
        requiresLogin: true
    },
    resolve: {
        currentUserAccount: ['domainService', function (domainService) {
            return domainService.currentUserAccount();
        }]
    }
})
```

Now the issue is that I need my `navbarCtrl` in the `root` state but this controller would not work there if the user is not logged in since the controller relies on data obtained when the user logs in:

```
.controller('NavbarCtrl', ['$scope', '$interval', 'messageService', 'currentUserAccount', function ($scope, $interval, messageService, currentUserAccount) {

    $scope.currentUserAccount = currentUserAccount.data;
    ...
```

Here is also my navbar template:

```
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navmenu" collapse="isCollapsed">
    <!--if user is not connected-->
    <ul ng-if="!authenticated" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Fonctionnalités</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">À propos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a class="btnNav btn btn-primary" role="button" ui-sref="signup.form" href="#">S'inscrire</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--if user is connected-->
    <ul ng-if="authenticated" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li ng-if="messageCount"><a ui-sref="message" href="#"><span style="font-size:16px;" class="glyphicon icon-email NewMail" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{messageCount}}</a></li>
        <li class="visible-xs"><a ui-sref="dashboard.useraccount.summary" href="#">Mon compte</a></li>
        <li class="visible-xs" ng-controller="SignoutCtrl"><a ng-click="signout()" href="#">Se déconnecter</a></li>
        <li class="hidden-xs">
            <section class="btn-group" dropdown>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="dropdown" dropdown-toggle>
                    <img ng-if="currentUserAccount.userAccountType==='PARENTS_TYPE'" src="assets/media/img/parents.svg" width="46" height="46" class="img-circle">
                    <img ng-if="currentUserAccount.userAccountType==='CHILDCARE_WORKER_TYPE'" src="assets/media/img/professionel.svg" width="46" height="46" class="img-circle">
                    {{currentUserAccount.firstName}}
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown">
                    <li><a ui-sref="dashboard.useraccount.summary" href="#"><span class="glyphicon icon-settings" aria-hidden="true"></span> Mon compte</a></li>
                    <li ng-controller="SignoutCtrl">
                        <a ng-click="signout()" href="#"><span class="glyphicon icon-lock" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{'SIGNOUT' | translate}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So I am not sure how to proceed with my navbar issue. I was thinking of checking whether `$rootScope.authenticated` is defined within `NavbarCtrl` but it does not seem right.

Comment: is the below suggestion helpful to you or you make it work in other way ?

Answer (score 0):

Your header controller should be in ancestor root abstract state and the dynamic functionality which you wants to handle (i.e. if the user is not logged in since the controller relies on data obtained when the user logs in) should be handled in it .You can handle the 2 header templates.(i.e. with login and without login) through ng-show/ng-hide in the header controller through scope variable states. In other words, header controller  should be written in a way that without authentication it should return the without login header and with authentication it should written the after login header.

Comment: Hi! I am just wondering whether it is considered a good practice to have that kind of conditional logic in a controller i.e. letting one controller handle authenticated and not-authenticated logic...